# Ajax PHP Live Search - Second Step Needed

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, search, live

I have a Ajax PHP MySQL live search that basically pulls out food items from a MySQL database and presents them in a drop-down list, as users enter they search term, one item per line, just like searching in Google.

What I need is a way to allow users to click on a particular result item, and for that to open up, just below the item clicked, a box with a few radio buttons listing options with various amounts of that particular food item. The user would then be able to select an amount option and click submit to save their selection.

I know PHP and MySQL and HTML quite well, but JS is a bit of a challenge, so I'd appreciate if you could be detailed in your answer.

Below are some code snippets with what I have at this point:

1. The HTML search form:

   ```
   <input type="text" size="30" name="food_name" id="q" value="" onkeyup="sendRequest(this.value);" autocomplete="off"/>
   ```
2. The AJAX code on same page w/ search form:

   ```
     function createRequestObject() {

     var req;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
     // Firefox, Safari, Opera...
     req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
     // Internet Explorer 5+
     req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
     alert('Problem creating the XMLHttpRequest object');
    }

    return req;

    }

   // Make the XMLHttpRequest object
   var http = createRequestObject();

   function sendRequest(q) {

    // Open PHP script for requests
     http.open('get', 'checkfoods.php?q='+q);
     http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
     http.send(null);

     }

     function handleResponse() {

     if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){

     // Text returned FROM the PHP script
     var response = http.responseText;

     if(response) {
        // UPDATE ajaxTest content
        document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = response;
     }

     }

     }
   ```
3. The PHP script that looks into a table called FOOD_DES into MySQL and brings back the results populating the drop-down list of foods:

   ```
     include 'my-food-dtabase.php';

     $searchQry = isset($_GET['q']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) : false;

     if ($searchQry) {
     $searchString = $_GET['q'];

     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT NDB_No, FdGrp_Cd, Long_Desc FROM FOOD_DES WHERE Long_Desc LIKE '%".$_GET['q']."%' ORDER BY Long_Desc ASC");

     if($searchString != NULL) {

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     echo "<span id=foodlist><a href=calorie-counter-serving.php?NDB_No=".$row['NDB_No'].">".$row['Long_Desc']."</a><br /></span>";
    }
    }

     if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
     echo "<span class=medium_white>Food item not found. Try a different name or keyword.</span>";
     }
     }
   ```

Comment: http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html#One

Comment: Make sure you can see the AJAX request/response when working on this - it helps enormously. Chrome has this natively, or Firefox+Firebug is good.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't necessarily a complete answer but a pointer in the right direction.

You will save yourself a tonne of time and effort by using jQuery over pure JavaScript. It will also reduce your step 2 down to a few lines of code as it comes with its own [Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Here's a [tutorial on its Ajax system](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) - much easier!

jQuery UI is a great extension to jQuery which helps you to build user interfaces, part of this is the dialog widget. I think the ['Modal form' dialog example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) is very similar to what you are trying to achieve when you click the 'create new user' button. Click 'View Source' to see how they did it.

Also from what I can see in step 3 you aren't sanitising your query, $_GET['q'] is being thrown right into your query string. You should replace this with $searchQry which you already defined a few lines above.

Comment: +1, yes definitely to a JS library. Google et al do everything natively to save a few KB per request - anyone not operating at such rarified heights should just use jQuery/MooTools/Prototype etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://koding.info/2013/07/ajax-search-box-php-mysql-jquery/
I have implemented a demo Live search application which uses Wordpress database.
Take a look.
it may help you.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do with Ajax, PHP and JQuery. Hope this helps or gives you a start.

See live demo and source code here.

http://purpledesign.in/blog/to-create-a-live-search-like-google/

Create a search box, may be an input field like this.

```
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
```

Now we need listen to whatever the user types on the text area. For this we will use the jquery live() and the keyup event. On every keyup we have a jquery function “search” that will run a php script.

Suppose we have the html like this. We have an input field and a list to display the results.

```
 <div class="icon"></div>
 <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
 <ul id="results"></ul>
```

We have a Jquery script that will listen to the keyup event on the input field and if it is not empty it will invoke the search() function. The search() function will run the php script and display the result on the same page using AJAX.

Here is the JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    //Listen for the event
        $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });


    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_st.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);

                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }



});
```

In the php, shoot a query to the mysql database. The php will return the results that will be put into the html using AJAX. Here the result is put into a html list.

Suppose there is a dummy database containing two tables animals and bird with two similar column names ‘type’ and ‘desc’.

```
  //search.php
    // Credentials
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "live";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";

    //  Connection
    global $tutorial_db;

    $tutorial_db = new mysqli();
    $tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

    //  Check Connection
    if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
        exit();

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<li class="result">';
    $html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
    $html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
    $html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
    $html .= '</a>';
    $html .= '</li>';

     $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = "SELECT *
     FROM animals
     WHERE type LIKE '%".$search_string."%'
     UNION ALL SELECT *
     FROM birf
     WHERE type LIKE '%".$search_string."%'"
     ;

    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
        while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array[] = $results;
        }

        // Check If We Have Results
        if (isset($result_array)) {
            foreach ($result_array as $result) {

                // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
                $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['desc']);
                $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['type']);
            $display_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='.urlencode($result['type']).'&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8';

                // Insert Name
                $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);

                // Insert Description
                $output = str_replace('functionString', $display_function, $output);

                // Insert URL
                $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);



                // Output
                echo($output);
            }
        }else{

            // Format No Results Output
            $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
            $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No Results Found.</b>', $output);
            $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }
```